# Get initial select event for the first tab of TabLayout when activity started

Tags: android, android-tablayout

In `onCreate`, I added a listener using `addOnTabSelectedListener`. It seems that `onTabSelected` is not called when the initial index is 0. How can I get this "selected 0" event?

Below is the timeline of what happens. The bold parts are the problem. I need to get notified that tab 0 is selected.

- Activity is created for the first time.
- **Tab 0 is automatically selected, but I do not get onTabSelected.**
- I click tab 1, I get onTabSelected with 1.
- I click tab 0, I get onTabSelected with 0.
- I click tab 1, I get onTabSelected with 1.
- I rotate the device.
- Tab 1 is automatically selected, I get onTabSelected with 1.
- I click tab 0, I get onTabSelected with 0.
- I rotate the device.
- **Tab 0 is automatically selected, but I do not get onTabSelected.**

Code

```
    myAdapter = MyTabAdapter(supportFragmentManager);
    viewPager.adapter = myAdapter;
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
```

Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call it manually

```
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
};
onTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()));
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener);
```

Comment: Won't that make onTabSelected called twice for the same tab if the initially selected tab is tab 1 (see that situation in my OP)?

Comment: Hmm that seems like a bug that it is not called with 0 at all when initializing TabLayout, is it problematic that it will get called twice sometimes?

Comment: On second thought I could just check if the selected is 0, and call it only that time. But the issue is the timing. I thought that event is called when the that tab has actually been changed. I was afraid if it is not too early to call that in onCreate. That is, the initial selection value is 0, but the actual tab (fragment) is not ready yet. I think I have to test it.